# Vue 3 composition api - Possibility to add custom element to defineComponent with handling on render

Tags: javascript, frontend, vuejs3, local-storage, vue-composition-api

Really need a vue pro here:).

Trying to find best solution for handling user additional claims inside components without huge refactor.

Claims are stored inside localStorage as a array of enums ex. [Claim.DictCreate, Claim.Update].

I have an idea to make something like

We have some component "Dictionary", which has his claims defined in user claims,

here in claims we define which claims are for what action for this specific view.

```
export default defineComponent({
claims: {
  create: Claim.DictCreate,
  edit: Claim.DictUpdate,
  delete: Claim.DictDelete
 },
setup: (claims) => {

 return {
  claims
 }
}
})
```

And here maybe is a option to have some logic to check user claims from localStorage once per application that takes claims from defineComponent in every component and then when we access this in setup it returns something like [createEnabled: true, editEnabled: false] after checking.

and then pass create, edit, delete to buttons on view

```
<edit-button v-if="claims.editEnabled">
```

Is there a way to handle this like that with some custom define component element?

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply pass the claims over props?

Like this

```
props: {    
    claims: {        
        type: Object,
        required: true        
    }    
}
```

To store the user claims you could use Vue [Composables](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/composables.html#what-is-a-composable)